# What do we call a person who wants to ship his vehicle from one state to another?

Tags: word-request

What do we call a person who wants to ship his or her car from one place to another?

I know the person who does it is a trucker or shipper, but I don't know what to call that person who wants to ship his car.

Comment: Is this a good question? Do you have some reason, or even research, to think that someone wishing to ship **a vehicle** would be named differently from someone wish to ship some other bulky item?

Answer (score 2):

You could say **client** or **customer**; for example: *the client who is shipping his car to Maryland*.

Comment: I worked with IT in logistics, and never heard any other terms for our customers.